# Simple curses.h program, nothing is showed in terminal

Tags: c, macos, netbeans

I have to use a curses.h library to my school project. We are programming in NetBeans. I am trying to create just simple program on my mac, everything seems be good. Code is compiled, a new terminal window is opened, but nothing is showed, just Press [ Enter ] to close the terminal. I have included curses.h library, set -lcurses in debug options (I have tried main.c -lcurses too). 
There is a screenshot.
  [screen](http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/459/screenxv.png)
Should I set anything else? Can you help me please?

EDIT:

Its really simply code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <curses.h>

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {

 initscr();

 printw("test");
 refresh();

 endwin();

 return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Comment: Please show your code as without it we can't help you

Comment: It is in the screenshot, to which I added a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `getch()` to wait for the user input between `refresh()` and `endwin()`. Your program ends too fast.

Comment: Thank you so much. :) Now "Test" is appeard, but why is not shown, when program ends? ... :)

Comment: @user2295495 Enjoy =) It is shown as `endwin()` is already called.